# Spring-boot executable tomcat with DLL

Tags: spring, tomcat, dll, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot web application that I would like to package as self executable jar. I have configured the plugin as described into the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar) and `java -jar myapp.jar` shows that the app is trying to start.

However, my app needs a DLL, so I have added a static block inside my servlet initializer :

```
public class DllUsageWebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("TheLibrary.dll");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DllUsageWebApp .class, args);
    }

}
```

But I receive the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception.

How can I add a DLL to the embedded tomcat server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your DLL library is included in the JAR file and can be loaded from classpath; if that's the case, all you need to do is copy that library somewhere on the file system where you can read it from.

```
public class DllUsageWebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    static {
        String tempLibraryFile = 
          copyResourceToTempDirFile("/path/to/dll/in/JAR", "my.dll");
        System.load(tempLibraryFile.absolutePath());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DllUsageWebApp .class, args);
    }

    public static File copyResourceToTempDirFile(
        String resourcePath, String destinationFileName) {
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File tempDirFile = new new File(tempDir, destinationFileName);
        try (InputStream input = resourceAsStream(resourcePath);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempDirFile)) {
            IOUtils.copy(input, output);
            tempDirFile.deleteOnExit();
            return tempDirFile;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that should be `load` rather than `loadLibrary`. AFAIK, the latter requires the library to be available on the `java.library.path` whereas the former takes a file name.